# Run Build Feature depends on configuration parameter

Tags: teamcity

I would like to use `File content replacer` build feature. But I need two different search/replace patterns depends on some configuration parameter `param1`. If `param1` starts with text 'first' then apply first search/replace pattern otherwise apply the second one. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is conditionally enable or disable a build feature (not necessarily an instance of *File Content Replacer*) depending on a configuration parameter value.

AFAIK, this is not possible. Instead, you can take a look at [Build Configuration Templates](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Build+Configuration+Template) or store your project settings in [Kotlin-based DSL](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Kotlin+DSL).